# pnpm install fails with azure devops (vsts) private package feed

Tags: azure-artifacts, pnpm

I have a private packages feed on Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) with a few packages.
I have a project configured (through .npmrc) to use that feed. `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc` (to configure auth for npm with the feed) completed with success.
If I run npm install, the modules installation runs successfully.
If I delete the node modules folder, the package lock and run pnpm install instead I get a `401 Unauthorized` error.
Computer is running windows 10 (latest public ring).
My question is: **how to configure pnpm to run properly with an azure devops private feed?**

Comment: I am not sure how azure devops works but I know that pnpm can read the configs from `.npmrc` and works with the auth tokens specified there.

Maybe pnpm cannot find the global npmrc file for some reason?

Comment: The vsts auth command I was mentioning stores the token in the windows identity store to avoid getting token stored on the repo through the file. Maybe the issue then is that pnpm is not looking in the windows identity store?

Comment: Do you use vsts-npm-auth for auth?

Comment: Yes, and it works with npm

Comment: That's weird, it works at my side.

Comment: And you are not storing the token in the npmrc file right?

Comment: Now there's a similar issue with pnpm v3 but I cannot find the reason of the regression. Maybe some of you has ideas: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/1815

Comment: The pnpm v3 regression was fixed in v3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after upgrading to pnpm v 2.17.8 so I guess it was a temporary issue/bug.